# How to list unused items from database

Tags: sql, oracle

`MDW_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS` has the following fields: `ACCOUNT_ID`, `MEAL_ID`.

`MDW_MEALS_MENU` has the following fields: `MEAL_ID`, `MEAL_NAME`.

I am trying to generate a report on the number of times a particular meal has been subscribed to by a customer using the query,

```
SELECT count(a.account_id), b.meal_id, b.meal_name
    FROM mdw_meals_menu b LEFT JOIN mdw_customer_accounts a
    on b.meal_id=a.meal_id
    WHERE
    a.start_date BETWEEN to_date('01-APR-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
    AND to_date('30-JUN-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
    GROUP BY b.meal_id, b.meal_name
    ORDER BY count(a.account_id) desc, b.meal_id;
```

This only lists the `MEAL_ID`s that has been subscribed to at least once. But it is not displaying the Ids that have not been subscribed to.

How do I get these `MEAL_ID`s to print with the count being `0`?

i have modified the code, but still i get the same result.

Comment: left join......

Comment: @MitchWheat i have tried using left join, but still no good for me...

Comment: SQL Fiddle of the bad query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2416/2/0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your where clause is effectively turning your outer join back into an inner join - conditions on an outer-joined table should generally be in the join clause, like so:

```
SELECT count(a.account_id), b.meal_id, b.meal_name
FROM mdw_meals_menu b 
LEFT JOIN mdw_customer_accounts a
       on b.meal_id=a.meal_id and
          a.start_date BETWEEN to_date('01-APR-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
                           AND to_date('30-JUN-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
GROUP BY b.meal_id, b.meal_name
ORDER BY count(a.account_id) desc, b.meal_id;
```

Comment: A SQL Fiddle for everyone, since I spent all that time making it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2416/1/0

Answer (score 1):

You should use a left outer join .

Comment: The OP is already using a left outer join (LEFT JOIN == LEFT OUTER JOIN)

Comment: Check the original question (before the 2nd Edit), the question originally showed a query with an implicit INNER JOIN, which was later edited to show an OUTER JOIN. This answer does answer the original question (albeit not in a great amount of detail), however I don't think it merits a downvote.

Comment: @GarethD - thanks for pointing that out - downvote cancelled.